# Google App Engine wont let me change payment settings in Dashboard

Tags: google-app-engine

**In my AppEngine dashboard my billing status says the following:**

```
Billing status
Enabled (Daily spending limit: Unlimited) Change
Enabled (Daily spending limit: $9,223,372.03) Settings
Quotas reset every 24 hours. Next reset: 9 hrs
```

[image]

**The "change" and "settings" links take me to a page where neither can be edited:**

[image]

**After clicking "Edit":**

[image]

A $9,223,372.03 default price seem a bit on the excessive side, don't ya think? Help pages are fairly useless, and support is non-existent without $150 price tag (which is almost extortion when one finds a bad UX issue like this, after taking the time to integrate with their services.).

I am hoping S.O. can tell me if I am missing something....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `USD` textbox (visible after pressing `Edit` in the app settings) is editable, set the number you desire:

[image]